# no name "urls" in module django

Tags: django, python-3.5, c9.io

I am unable to import from the django.urls package in Django 2.1.7
Really would like a solution to this problem. Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(' ',views.index, name ='index'),
]
```

Comment: post code instead of screenshots

Comment: from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
 path(' ',views.index, name ='index'),

Comment: Post it in the question, not comments

Comment: which version of django are you using? can you show the result of django.VERSION?

Comment: (env)yahsharahla1:~/workspace $ pip freeze
Django==2.1.7
pytz==2018.9

Comment: Which IDEA/editor are you using? have you properly set it up to use your virtualenv?

Comment: Currently using c9.io IDE. Not sure if the virtualenv is properly set up nor how i would go about doing that.

Comment: Then that is the problem. If the IDE is not setup to use the virtual env it wouldn't recognize django and other libs installed in the env. You can google how to setup virtualenv in c9.io

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, i'll check it out

Comment: @Ken4scholars, You where right, the c9 IDE was using the wrong version of django. So event though i am using a virtualenv, the version of django on the virtualenv and on c9 IDE needs to be the same. Much thanks for the assistance

Comment: They shouldn't just be the same versions. You need to use that exact virtual env in the IDE too.